# Array of object is always null in MVC core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to post array of a simple object to my MVC core controller with the Frombody attribute, but for some reason it coming as null. If I post just a single object it is working fine here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tk = new Array();

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        },

        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        alldayslot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotminutes: 15,
        nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00",
        events: "/Home/FullCalendar",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc)
        {
            Update(event);
        },
    });

    function Update(event) {
        var datarow =
            {
                "id": event.id, 
                "start": event.start,
                "end": event.end,
            }
        tk.push(datarow);

        debugger;
        confirm(("Save changes?"))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(datarow));
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(tk),
            url: '@Url.Action("JSON", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My Controller class

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateTask([FromBody] List<Task_fullcal> td)
{
    // Do something
    // td is always null if passed as an array 
    //td working fine if passed as single value
}
```

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ tk: tk }),`

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your reply but it is still not working. I am still getting null reference in the controller and this is what I get in the request body. 
[{"id":6,"start":"2016-10-03T00:30:00","end":null},{"id":7,"start":"2016-10-04T00:10:00","end":"2016-10-05T01:00:00"}]

Comment: Does `Task_fullcal` contain properties `int id`, `DateTime start` and `DateTime  end`? (and that was supposed to be `{ td: tk }` (not `{ tk: tk })`)

Comment: Yes this is the model.
    public class Task_fullcal
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
    }

it seems like Fullcalendar is sending the array as query string . but i don't know how to get the query string into my action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I spent few hours to figure out. I wrote the solution in

[Pass array of objects to controller by jQuery AJAX, action data is always null in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC - it is working with .NET Framework 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266290/pass-array-of-objects-to-controller-by-jquery-ajax-action-data-is-always-null-i/59377957#59377957)

Follow below:

---

I'm working in .Net Core 3.1 and this works for me:

**1. Controller**

Try **[FromForm]** instead **[FromBody]**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOrdersPOSTObject([FromForm] List<T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp> prm)
    {
        //your logic...
        return Json(new { msg = "Successfully added " });
    }
```

**2. AJAX Call**

Neither **JSON.stringfy()** nor **contentType** should be used.

```
            var DATA = [];
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12", LocProductID: "1002", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "soap", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "23", LocProductID: "1003", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "shampoo", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "7",LocProductID: "1004" ,discount: "0",posNumber: "2" ,productName: "sponge",productQynt: "2"});

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/home/CreateOrdersPOSTObject")',
                data: { "prm": DATA },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true
            });
```

Or if you prefer, you can use the shorthand **$.post** with the same results

```
            var DATA = [];
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12", LocProductID: "1002", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "soap", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "23", LocProductID: "1003", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "shampoo", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "7",LocProductID: "1004" ,discount: "0",posNumber: "2" ,productName: "sponge",productQynt: "2"});

            $.post(
                '@Url.Content("~/home/CreateOrdersPOSTObject")',
                { "prm": DATA },
                function () {
                  alert( "success" );
                })
              .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
              });
```

Comment: +1000 for the hint of not using `contentType`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove FromBody in your action, for complex types the Request will contain complex types in Request body.
try use PostMan and try different options.

1 pass object in URL , use [FromUri]

2 pass object in body ,remove FromBody

3 pass simple values like string ,use [FromUri] if you want to access from URL

4 pass simple values like string in Request body ,use [FromBody]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I converted it to a JSON string in the view:

```
var seatsJson = JSON.stringify(seats);
```

Then, in the action, I used Newtonsoft to cast it to an array of objects:

```
var seats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SeatsModel[]>(seatsjson);
```