# Pass array of objects to controller by jQuery AJAX, action data is always null in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC - it is working with .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working in project that I need to use ajax call to save object data from my page witch contain order details. When I use project with .NET framework version 4.5, it is working very well - but when I use ASP.NET Core MVC, it is not working. Any help please?

I did try every thing in similar questions but they did not work. For example I use notation `[frombody]` - but I still have the same problem.

I have the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrders([FromBody] T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp []T_POS_ENT_ORDER_Data)
{
    GRepository<T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp> t_pos_ent_orderOpr = new GRepository<T T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp>();

    T_POS_ENT_ORDER_Data.order_Date = DateTime.Now;
    t_pos_ent_orderOpr.Add(T_POS_ENT_ORDER_Data);

    return Json(new { msg = "Successfully added " }); 
}
```

And I have the following ajax call:

```
    var DATA = [];
    DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12" });
    DATA.push({ LocProductID: "1002" });
    DATA.push({ discount: "0" });
    DATA.push({ posNumber: "1" });
    DATA.push({ productName: "soap" });
    DATA.push({ productQynt: "1" });
    $.ajax({

    url: '/AjaxT_POS_ENT_ORDER/CreateOrders',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'billArray': DATA }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,

    success: OnSuccess,

  });
```

I also have this class:

```
public class T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp
{
    public string LocPrice { get; set; }
    public string LocProductID { get; set; }
    public string discount { get; set; }
    public string  posNumber { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public int productQynt { get; set; }
}
```

There is no error showing only the order details is always null ...

Answer (score 4):

I'm working in .Net Core 3.1 and this works for me:

**1. Controller**

Try **[FromForm]** instead **[FromBody]**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOrdersPOSTObject([FromForm] List<T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp> prm)
    {
        //your logic...
        return Json(new { msg = "Successfully added " });
    }
```

**2. AJAX Call**

Neither **JSON.stringfy()** nor **contentType** should be used.

```
            var DATA = [];
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12", LocProductID: "1002", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "soap", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "23", LocProductID: "1003", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "shampoo", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "7",LocProductID: "1004" ,discount: "0",posNumber: "2" ,productName: "sponge",productQynt: "2"});

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/home/CreateOrdersPOSTObject")',
                data: { "prm": DATA },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true
            });
```

Or if you prefer, you can use the shorthand **$.post** with the same results

```
            var DATA = [];
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12", LocProductID: "1002", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "soap", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "23", LocProductID: "1003", discount: "0", posNumber: "1", productName: "shampoo", productQynt: "1" });
            DATA.push({ LocPrice: "7",LocProductID: "1004" ,discount: "0",posNumber: "2" ,productName: "sponge",productQynt: "2"});

            $.post(
                '@Url.Content("~/home/CreateOrdersPOSTObject")',
                { "prm": DATA },
                function () {
                  alert( "success" );
                })
              .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
              });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing I got to work after trying different solutions for a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `JSON.stringify({ 'billArray': DATA })` to `JSON.stringify(DATA)` like below:

1.View:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var DATA = [];
        DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12" });
        DATA.push({ LocProductID: "1002" });
        DATA.push({ discount: "0" });
        DATA.push({ posNumber: "1" });
        DATA.push({ productName: "soap" });
        DATA.push({ productQynt: "1" });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/AjaxT_POS_ENT_ORDER/CreateOrders',
            data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateOrders([FromBody] T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp[] T_POS_ENT_ORDER_Data)
{
    //your logic...
    return Json(new { msg = "Successfully added " });
}
```

3.Result:
[image]

By the way, if you want to pass them as one array object instead of six arrays,you need to change your DATA  like below:

```
DATA.push({ LocPrice: "12",LocProductID: "1002" ,discount: "0",posNumber: "1" ,productName: "soap",productQynt: "1"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an array in your data, there is only a single object with some fields. Also `billArray` does not match `T_POS_ENT_ORDER_Data`, and model binding is done by name matching.

To fix this, you should adjust your code to only post and receive a single object.:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrders(T_POS_ENT_ORDER_DETIALS_Temp T_POS_ENT_ORDER_Data)

...

var DATA = {
    LocPrice: "12",
    LocProductID: "1002",
    discount: "0",
    posNumber: "1",
    productName: "soap",
    productQynt: "1"
 });

$.ajax({
    url: '/AjaxT_POS_ENT_ORDER/CreateOrders',
    data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: OnSuccess
});
```

Minor, there is a typo in class name "DETIALS" -> "DETAILS".

Comment: i did every thing you said but still the object is null when i make debug in the controller

Comment: Try reducing the passed object to a single string, go right back to basics and build up from there. DATA = "XXX" and in your controller use [HttpPost] CreateOrders(string thing) etc...